# Ionic UI not showing up

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, capacitor, ionic5

I was following along [this tutorial](https://www.techiediaries.com/ionic/ionic-5-tutorial-storage-crud-theming-example/). The first problem I encountered was in the file **todo.service.ts**;

> Property 'key' does not exist on type 'Todo'

Below is the code to the interface **todo.ts**:

```
export interface Todo {
    title:string;
    note:string;
    completed:boolean;
}
```

Here is the code to the **todo.service.ts**:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';
import { Todo } from './todo';

@Injectable({
   providedIn: 'root'
})
export class TodoService {

constructor(public storage: Storage) { }

public async generateKey(): Promise<string>{
   let key = `todo${ parseInt(`${Math.random() * 100}`)}`;
   let ret = await this.storage.get(key);

   while(ret){
     key= `todo${ parseInt(`${Math.random() * 100}`)}`;
     ret = await this.storage.get(key);
   }

   return key;
 }

 public async read(): Promise<Todo[]>{
    let todos: Array<Todo> = [];
    await this.storage.forEach((v, key, i)=>{
      if(key.startsWith("todo")){
         todos.push(v);
      }
    });

    return todos;
}

public async create(key: string, todo: Todo){
    console.log("Creating todo: ", todo);
    return await this.storage.set(key, todo);
}

public async update(todo: Todo){
   return await this.storage.set(todo.key, todo);
}

public async delete(key: string){
   return await this.storage.remove(key);
}
```

}

The error that I got is in the update method in **todo.service.ts** above. When I added `key:string` in the interface (**todos.ts**), the error disappears.

Below is the **home.page.ts** before I added `key:string`:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { TodoService } from '../todo.service';
import { Todo } from '../todo';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
})
export class HomePage {

  public todos: Array<Todo> = [];
  constructor(public todoService: TodoService) {}

  async ngOnInit(){
    this.todos = await this.todoService.read();
  }

  getIcon(todo){
    if(todo.completed) return 'checkmark-circle';
    else return 'stopwatch';
  }

  public async createTodo(){
    let key = await this.todoService.generateKey();
    let todo = {
      title: `${key}`
      note: "A new todo",
      completed:true
    };
    await this.todoService.create(key, todo);
    this.todos = await this.todoService.read();
  }

}
```

After adding `key:string` in **todos.ts**;

```
export interface Todo {
    key:string;
    title:string;
    note:string;
    completed:boolean;
}
```

I updated the createTodo() as below:

```
public async createTodo(){
 let key = await this.todoService.generateKey();
 let todo = {
    title: `${key}`
    note: "A new todo",
    key: key,
    completed:true
  };
  await this.todoService.create(key, todo);
  this.todos = await this.todoService.read();
}
```

Below is the **home.page.html** which is the exact same thing as in the tutorial.

```
<ion-header translucent>
  <ion-toolbar color="primary">

    <ion-title>
      Todo
    </ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>

</ion-header>

<ion-content color="primary" fullscreen>
  <ion-header collapse="condense">
    <ion-toolbar>
      <ion-title size="large">Todo</ion-title>
    </ion-toolbar>
  </ion-header>

  <ion-button (click)="createTodo()" color="secondary" expand="block">
    Add todo
    <ion-icon name="add-circle" slot="start"></ion-icon>
  </ion-button>

  <ion-list style="background: var(--ion-color-primary);">

    <ion-item color="primary" *ngFor="let todo of todos">
      <ion-icon [name]="getIcon(todo)" slot="start">

      </ion-icon>



      <div slot="end">

      </div>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>

</ion-content>
```

After running the program with `ionic serve`, the home page UI does not show up at all, it's just a blank screen. I head over to `localhost:8100/about`, the about page does show up. But when I go to `localhost:8100/home`, it redirects to `localhost:8100` and shows nothing. Does anyone knows where or what the problem is? I've been trying to solve just this for the whole day.

**[UPDATE]:**

I do get to show up the UI, but it still got a problem to show up the todo list. The changes I made is in the constructor in **home.page.ts**.

Before:

```
export class HomePage {

  public todos: Array<Todo> = [];
  
  
  constructor(public todoService: TodoService){}
  ...
  ...
  ...
}
```

After:

```
export class HomePage {
    
   public todos: Array<Todo> = [];
   public todoService: TodoService;   
      
   constructor(){}
   ...
   ...
   ...
}
```

I deleted `public todoService: TodoService` from the constructor() parameter, and moved it outside of the constructor. The UI does show up, but the todos list is missing.
Does anybody know the solution to this?

Comment: Hello! Could you create a Stackblitz demo with your code, please? You can use this **[Ionic 5 starter project](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-5-starter-app)** if you want (the storage module is already installed, so that should work as well). Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
 public async createTodo(){
    let key = await this.todoService.generateKey();
    let todo = {
      title: `${key}`, 
      note: "A new todo",
      completed:true
    };
    await this.todoService.create(key, todo);
    this.todos = await this.todoService.read();
  }
```

There is a comma missing after `title` value. Maybe it will solve the problem. If not, could you tell me the IDE you're using to code with.
If there is something wrong, your IDE should give you some errors, or hints.

When copying your code in my `Webstorm IDE`, it was full of errors...

Comment: Hi, I've added the comma, while the UI does show up, the todo list is still not showing up. I'm coding it using VSCode. The first error hinted by VSCode was as mentioned in the question, in the `update()`, thus I added `key:string`.